# Tokenizing an algebraic expression in string format

Tags: java

I"m trying to take a string that represents a full algebraic excpression, such as x = 15 * 6 / 3 which is a string, and tokenize it into its individual components.  So the first would be x, then =, then 15, then *, 6, / and finally 3.

The problem I am having is actually parsing through the string and looking at the individual characters.  I can't think of a way to do this without a massive amount of if statements.  Surely there has to be a better way tan specifically defining each individual case and testing for it.

Comment: for your case all of the symbols are separated by space ? if so you could hack with `split();`

Comment: I think what you probably want is a finite state machine.

Comment: Well, you can't do it with a state machine, at least not counting things like the order of operations.  Thinking in the right direction though - you'd need a pushdown automaton for this.  (PDAs are like state machines but have a stack instead of a fixed set of memory).  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton

Comment: @Wug He can do the *tokenizing* with an FSM, which is what he's asking about.

Comment: Mmm yeah, I'm getting ahead of myself.  Won't be able to calculate the answer without a PDA.  Tokenizing, yes, you can.  My bad.

Comment: I've provided my, possibly inefficient-ugly, implementations of the number & phrase extractors. See edit.

Answer (score 3):

For each type of token, you'll want to figure out how to identify:

- when you're starting to read a particular token
- if you're continuing to read the same token, or if you've started a different one

Let's take your example:  `x=15*6/3`.  Let's assume that you cannot rely on the fact that there are spaces in between each token.  In that case, it's trivial: your new token starts when you reach a space.

You can break down the character types into letters, digits, and symbols.  Let's call the token types Variable, Operator, and Number.

A letter indicates a Variable token has started.  It continues until you read a non-letter.

A symbol indicates the start of an Operator token.  I only see single symbols, but you can have groups of symbols correspond to different Operator tokens.

A digit indicates the start of a Number token.  (Let's assume integers for now.)  The Number token continues until you read a non-digit.

Basically, that's how a simple symbolic parser works.  Now, if you add in negative numbers (where the '-' symbol can have multiple meanings), or parentheses, or function names (like `sin(x)`) then things get more complicated, but it amounts to the same set of rules, now just with more choices.

Answer (score 2):

This is from my early expression evaluator that takes an infix expression like yours and turns it into postfix to evaluate. There are methods that help the parser but I think they're pretty self documenting. Mine uses symbol tables to check tokens against. It also allows for user defined symbols and nested assignments and other things you may not need/want. But it shows how I handled your issue without using niceties like regex which would simplify this task tremendously. In addition everything shown is of my own implementation - stack and queue as well - *everything*. So if anything looks abnormal (unlike Java imps) that's because it is.

This section of code is important not to answer your immediate question but to show the necessary work to determine the type of token you're dealing with. In my case I had three different types of operators and two different types of operands. Based on either the known rules or rules I chose to enforce (when appropriate) it was easy to know when something was a number (starts with a number), variable/user symbol/math function (starts with a letter), or math operator (is: /,*,-,+) . Note that it only takes seeing the first `char` to know the correct extraction rules. From your example, if all your cases are as simple, you'd only have to handle two types, operator or operand. Nonetheless the same logic will apply.

```
protected Queue<Token> inToPostParse(String exp) {
    // local vars
    inputExp = exp;
    offset = 0;
    strLength = exp.length();
    String tempHolder = "";
    char c;

    // the program runs in a loop so make sure you're dealing
    // with an empty queue
    q1.reset();

    for (int i = offset; tempHolder != null && i < strLength; ++i) {
        c = exp.charAt(i); 

        // Spaces are useless so skip them
        if (c == ' ') { continue; }

        // If c is a letter
        if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z')
                || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')) {

            // Here we know it must be a user symbol possibly undefined
            // at this point or an function like SIN, ABS, etc
            // We extract, based on obvious rules, the op
            tempHolder = extractPhrase(i); // Used to be append sequence
            if (ut.isTrigOp(tempHolder) || ut.isAdditionalOp(tempHolder)) {
                s1.push(new Operator(tempHolder, "Function"));
            } else {
                // If not some math function it is a user defined symbol
                q1.insert(new Token(tempHolder, "User"));
            }
            i += tempHolder.length() - 1;
            tempHolder = "";

        // if c begins with a number
        } else if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            try {
                // Here we know that it must be a number
                // so we extract until we reach a non number
                tempHolder = extractNumber(i);
                q1.insert(new Token(tempHolder, "Number"));
                i += tempHolder.length() - 1;
                tempHolder = "";
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                return null;
            }

        // if c is in the math symbol table
        } else if (ut.isMathOp(String.valueOf(c))) {
            String C = String.valueOf(c);
            try {
                // This is where the magic happens
                // Here we determine the "intersection" of the 
                // current C and the top of the stack
                // Based on the intersection we take action
                // i.e., in math do you want to * or + first?
                // Depending on the state you may have to move
                // some tokens to the queue before pushing onto the stack 
                takeParseAction(C, ut.findIntersection
                            (C, s1.showTop().getSymbol()));
            }
            catch (NullPointerException npe) {
                s1(C);
            }
        // it must be an invalid expression
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    u2();
    s1.reset();
    return q1;
}
```

Basically I have a stack (s1) and a queue (q1). All variables or numbers go into the queue. Any operators trig, math, parens, etc.. go on the stack. If the current token is to be put on the stack you have to check the state (top) to determine what parsing action to take (i.e., what to do based on math precedence). Sorry if this seems like useless information. I imagine if you're parsing a math expression it's because at some point you plan to evaluate it. IMHO, postfix is the easiest so I, regardless of input format, change it to post and evaluate with one method. If your O is different - do what you like.

**Edit:** Implementations
The extract phrase and number methods, which you may be most interested in, are as follows:

```
protected String extractPhrase(int it) {
    String phrase = new String();
    char c;
    for ( ; it < inputExp.length(); ++it) {
        c = inputExp.charAt(it);
        if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
                        || (c >= '0' && c <= '9')) {
                    phrase += String.valueOf(c);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return phrase;
}

protected String extractNumber(int it) throws NumberFormatException {
    String number = new String();
    int decimals = 0;
    char c;
    for ( ; it < strLength; ++it) {
        c = inputExp.charAt(it);
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
            number += String.valueOf(c);
        } else if (c == '.') {
            ++decimals;
            if (decimals < 2) {
                number += ".";
            } else {
                throw new NumberFormatException();
            }               
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return number;
}
```

Remember - By the time they enter these methods I've already been able to deduce what type it is. This allows you to avoid the seemingly endless while-if-else chain.

Answer (score 2):

1. create regular expression for each possible element: integer, variable, operator, parentheses.
2. combine them using the `|` regular expression operator into one big regular expression with capture groups to identify which one matched.
3. in a loop match the head of the remaining string and break off the matched part as a token. the type of the token depends on which sub-expression matched as described in 2.

or

use a lexer library, such as the one in antlr or javacc

Comment: ps: regular expressions == finite state automata

Answer (score 1):

Are components always separated by space character like in your question? if so, use `algebricExpression.split(" ")` to get a `String[]` of components.

If no such restrictions can be assumed, a possible solution can be to iterate over the input, and `switch` the Character.getType() of the current index, somthing like that:

```
ArrayList<String> getExpressionComponents(String exp) {
    ArrayList<String> components = new ArrayList<String>();
    String current = "";
    int currentSequenceType = Character.UNASSIGNED;


    for (int i = 0 ; i < exp.length() ; i++) {
        if (currentSequenceType != Character.getType(exp.charAt(i))) {
            if (current.length() > 0) components.add(current);
            current = "";
            currentSequenceType = Character.getType(exp.charAt(i));
        }
        switch (Character.getType(exp.charAt(i))) {
            case Character.DECIMAL_DIGIT_NUMBER: 
            case Character.MATH_SYMBOL: 
            case Character.START_PUNCTUATION: 
            case Character.END_PUNCTUATION:
            case Character.LOWERCASE_LETTER:
            case Character.UPPERCASE_LETTER:
            // add other required types
                current = current.concat(new String(new char[] {exp.charAt(i)}));
                currentSequenceType = Character.getType(exp.charAt(i));
                break;
            default: 
                current = "";
                currentSequenceType = Character.UNASSIGNED;
                break;
        }
    }
    return components;
}
```

You can easily change the cases to meet with other requirements, such as split non-digit chars to separate components etc.