# How to create a calculator application which will take value+operator as input and will do the calculation, print result on to the screen.

Tags: user-interface, android

I am creating a calculator in android and I want to create a ui with history option so that user can view their calculation history.

I have added screenshot from another application which has similar functionality. I don't know what to call this kind of gui. [Here is the link to the application from where the gui was taken](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.candl.athena)

In the screenshot you can see that the user can see the history of the calculation.

How to create a calculator application which will take value+operator as input and will do the calculation and print it on screen and should also show history of calculations.

[image: here is the screenshot]

Comment: Try storing all the entries into an arraylist. Maybe you could do like this. Or wait for some other helpful inputs :)

Comment: that's what i did but my problem is that how shall i take both vales+operator(9000+1) as input and then do calculation and print it on screen.

Comment: Are you facing difficulty in showing the history like `10+1`? You need to append the operator in between the numbers, try to come up with a logic.

Comment: so when that user inputs(10+1), i need to convert it to string then parse string and separate numbers and operators, do calculation and then print it on screen??

Comment: What difficulty are you facing? To print the result? It's pretty easy. Convert to string? FYI, when user gives inputs they will be in `String`, not `int`.  As far as I remember you need to review answer for your other post.

Comment: My problem separation of operators and values. if user inputs (258(10+6)/10), in this case do i need to store string in stack(from left to right side and store according to brackets and operators ) and then perform calculation by bringing each element from the top of stack and performing calculation accordingly and then printing it on screen??

Comment: You're asking many questions here. First, you need to parse it into, IMHO, post-fix. This allows you to eliminate those pesky parens and it establishes math presedence. Then you perform the operations, get and display the result. On top of that you wish to store the history into a drawer! This is a ridiculously long answer.

Comment: [This is a small fraction of the code required to do what you're asking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157559/tokenizing-an-algebraic-expression-in-string-format/17157809#17157809).

Comment: thanks. i know it is very long but can't help it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wish to go for The [Operator precedence parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser). An algorithm used to evaluate expressions. I really appreciate your idea.